# javascript - unused argument 'idtype' although called from a .map() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to re-write a function that filters out a specific property of an object to a function that can be passed a property and filter it.

This is the initial function:

```
function filterCategory(xmlObject, id) {
  let newData = [];
  xmlObject
      .Sports[0]
      .Sport[0]
      .Category
      .map(function (category) {
        if (category.$.CategoryID == id) {
          newData.push(category);
        }
      });
  xmlObject
      .Sports[0]
      .Sport[0]
      .Category = newData;
  return xmlObject;
}
```

This is my new function:

```
function filterProperty(xmlObject, property, idtype, id) {
  let newData = [];

  if(xmlObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
    xmlObject.property.map(function(value) {
      if(value.$.idtype == id) {
        newData.push(value);
      }
    });
    xmlObject.property = newData;
  }
  return xmlObject;
}
```

For the second function my linter returns Unused `idtype`. Will my function be able to access the argument, or will it fail because I am trying to call it from a `map()` function? If so, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Why do you have the `idtype` parameter if the function doesn't use it?

Comment: it is used here if(value.$.idtype == id) {

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: `value.$.idtype` doesn't refer to the function's parameter, does it?

Comment: Well in theory it should, I just don;t know how to write it properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `idtype` as a dynamic object property, then you can't use it like `my.object.idtype` as that will look for the property on the object that is literally called "idtype", instead you can use bracket notation to access the property

```
value.$[idtype];
```

Further illustration:

```js
var obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 'foobarbaz' };

function getThingFromObject(mything) {  
  return obj[mything];
}

console.log(getThingFromObject('one')); // 1
console.log(getThingFromObject('three')); // 'foobarbaz'
```